SQL adding entries in a range
For example, if I had a table named "Periods", with column (type:date)
Would I be able to make a stored procedure, where given (date), i will add an entry to the table for every 2 weeks from the given date, until it reaches lets say 10 weeks?
So If i enter like July 1st, it will add table entries that are, July 15th, July 30th , something like that?
could this be accomplished in SQL maybe in a stored procedure or just with queries? or am I better off writing something like a trigger/ api
I see that there are options, but I see that loops are frowned upon in SQL? wondering if there is a good solution to this problem

A trigger in the Period table to add more period entries will be a mutation.  food for thought

A recursive WITH (cte) can be used too.

Which dbms are you using? Don't waste other users' time writing answers for "wrong" products.

"Would I be able to make a stored procedure..."  No,but that's why you are asking....

Recursive CTE that inserts, into the periods table, 1 record for every 2 weeks for up to 10 weeks for a given start date. SQL-Server example.
CREATE PROC AddRecordEvery2weeksFor10Weeks @startdate Date
AS
BEGIN
    WITH dates AS
    (
        SELECT @startdate AS d
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            DATEADD(WEEK, 2, d)
        FROM dates
        WHERE d < dateadd(week, 10, @startdate) --end after 10 weeks
    )
    INSERT INTO Periods ([date])
    SELECT d FROM dates 
    WHERE d > @startdate;
END;


Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell OP (and the rest of us) which dbms this is for.
